# compiling assembly code on mac os big sur (x8664)

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, nasm, macos-big-sur

Hello I would like to begin coding a little in assembly.

I have installed the latest nasm version (2.15). I followed all the steps and I set up nasm correctly.

Now I wanted to run my first hello world program using:

```
nasm -f macho64 hello.asm
```

or also

```
nasm -fmacho64 hello.asm && ld hello.o && ./a.out
```

or also

```
nasm -f macho64 hello.asm -o hell.o  && ld -e _main -macosx_version_min 10.8 -arch x86_64 hello.o -lSystem
```

and none of these work. Actually `nasm -f macho64 hello.asm` does not throw errors but does not print to the screen either. This is the code I copied and pasted to see if everything worked:

```
; Writes "Hello, World" to the console using only system calls. Runs on 64-b
; To assemble and run:
;
;     nasm -fmacho64 hello.asm && ld hello.o && ./a.out
; --------------------------------------------------------------------------

          global    start

          section   .text
start:    mov       rax, 0x02000004         ; system call for write
          mov       rdi, 1                  ; file handle 1 is stdout
          mov       rsi, message            ; address of string to output
          mov       rdx, 13                 ; number of bytes
          syscall                           ; invoke operating system to do 
          mov       rax, 0x02000001         ; system call for exit
          xor       rdi, rdi                ; exit code 0
          syscall                           ; invoke operating system to exi

          section   .data
message:  db        "Hello, World", 10      ; note the newline at the end
```

and this is the error that I get from running the other two commands:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Could someone help me and tell me how to set up everything correctly. As I said the command `nasm -f macho64 hello.asm` does not give any error but it does not print anything out but it should, so either it is a problem with the actual code or it is a problem with nasm itself. Could you also give me a brief explanation of why the other two commands fail. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: No – `nasm` shouldn't be any louder than that. If there are no errors to print, `nasm` won't print anything. The same stands for e.g. `gcc`.

Comment: yeah I could manage to print something on the screen by using the following nasm -fmacho64 hello.asm && gcc hello.o && ./a.out

Answer (score 1):

You'll just need to adjust your code a little and link it with the correct switches (see `_main` instead of `start`):

```
          global    _main

          section   .text
_main:    mov       rax, 0x02000004         ; system call for write
          mov       rdi, 1                  ; file handle 1 is stdout
          mov       rsi, message            ; address of string to output
          mov       rdx, 13                 ; number of bytes
          syscall                           ; invoke operating system to do 
          mov       rax, 0x02000001         ; system call for exit
          xor       rdi, rdi                ; exit code 0
          syscall                           ; invoke operating system to exi

          section   .data
message:  db        "Hello, World", 10      ; note the newline at the end
```

```
$ nasm -fmacho64 hello.asm && ld -e _main hello.o -lSystem && ./a.out
Hello, World
$
```

Comment: Generally not a good idea to call something `_main` if it's not *actually* called as main with a valid return address, and argc, argv, and libc initialized.  Instead of changing the symbol in the source code, would it make more sense to just change the `ld` arg to `-e start`?  Or does this command still run CRT init functions and stuff, so you could use `ret` if you wanted to instead of an `_exit` system call?